# Timeout when running web app in Heroku - fine when running locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

I'm an iOS developer by trade so please forgive me for my doubt no ignorant question...

I have a web app that is being deployed to heroku, I have a package installed ([GetVideo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getvideo)), and I'm making a call to my `/video?url=xxx` endpoint to retrieve the URL for a video. Works absolutely fine locally (if a little slow - 1000ms). When I deploy this app, and make the some call to Heroku I get this timeout error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="
```

Which is odd.

Here is the code used for the endpoint, very basic.

```
app.get('/video', (req, response) => {
  var url = req.query.url;
  getVideo(url, function(err, video) {
        if (err) {
          response.status(500).send(err.message);
        } else {
          response.send({video})
      }
    });
})
```

Any suggestions to stop the error?

Comment: It looks like your request is taking longer than Heroku's threshold? Did you get any hints from the docs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: Ive glanced over them - I guess the question is more like, why would it take 30x longer on a Heroku dyno than when run locally?

Comment: for some long running processes that timeout on heroku, the use of a service worker maybe advisable. https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-articles-nlp for example